# Maximum number of TCP connections

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, omnet++

I am doing a TCP client - server simulation. In the simulation, I have created 2 clients and 2 servers. And I have programmed that read requests will go to server 1 and write requests will go to server 2. Thus, the client will always renew it's socket and make a new connection to the servers.

However, after the client has made 66561 times of connections to the server, instead of sending request packets, it will just simply send some empty ACK packets.

I expected both the clients to be able to send up to millions of requests, but currently, both the clients are only able to send up to 13k requests. Can anyone give me tips or advices?

Comment: Why do you open and close your connections so often? Why not just establish the two connections and use them?

Comment: TCP connection handshake is (comparatively) complex and time-consuming, and involves a few packet exchanges. Avoid it if you can. That's why e.g. HTTP nowadays have [persistent connections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection).

Comment: Oh, and you do properly close the connections on the server side when the client disconnects?

Comment: What you do is bad because sockets are expensive to establish and should be re-used, but it should work. Simply the code you failed to show must contains implementation flaws.

Comment: Because, the 2 clients are connecting to 2 servers, depending on the kind of requests. If i don't open and close the connection, the client will just kept on sending requests to the same server

Comment: But what i am confused is, why does the client stop sending any more requests after a certain connections. Is there a limit on how many times the client can connect to the server?

Comment: Sockets are like any other resource on a computer, limited. If you don't clean up properly you will sooner or later run out of sockets. Again, you *do* clean up properly after you disconnect? And if you need to communicate with two servers, why not simply open two connections, one to each server, and then keep the connections open? And you *do* correctly check for errors and report them correctly?

Comment: Finally, please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: OmNeT++ has restricted me to open two connections.

Comment: Please add that code snippet for the server to the initial question, not to a comment. But if this really is C++, and the snippet is complete, then you are leaking pointers on mass, and with it probably also the still open sockets.

Comment: I have solved it, thanks people!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like most previously created connections are still taking the resource (not released from system). From the information you give,

However, after the client has made 66561 times of connections to the server, instead of sending request packets, it will just simply send some empty ACK packets.

Looks like about 1000+ connections are released. Probably because of the 2msl time is due. If this is the case, suggest you explicitly release a connect before you create a new one.

Copy and paste your C/S part code would help the analyse.

Comment: this is the coding for the server.

Comment: its too long, i can't copy and paste. damnn it

Comment: if(appmsg->getRead() == 1) {
GenericAppMsg *ack = new GenericAppMsg("READ_ACK");
TCPSendCommand *cmd = new TCPSendCommand();
 cmd->setConnId(connId);
 ack->setRequestID(appmsg->getRequestID());
ack->setStartTime(appmsg->getStartTime());
ack->setServerSend(SIMTIME_DBL(appmsg->getArrivalTime()));
send(ack,"tcpOut"); ack->setServerArrive(SIMTIME_DBL(appmsg->getArrivalTime()));

Answer (score 1):

[Nagle's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm)

Solutions:

- Do not use small package in your app protocol
- Use socket option **TCP_NODELAY** on both side client/server